# Creating PolylineZ in arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, geometry

The script below is slightly modified "Polyline example" from ArcGIS help http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000008000000

```
import arcpy
# next 3 lines are new
from arcpy import env
env.outputZFlag = "Enabled"
env.outputMFlag = "Enabled"

# A list of features and coordinate pairs
# 3rd presumably Z coordinate added to original pairs of XY
feature_info = [[[1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 2], [3, 7, 3]],
                [[6, 8, 4], [5, 7, 5], [7, 2, 6], [9, 5, 7]]]

# A list that will hold each of the Polyline objects
features = []

for feature in feature_info:
    # Create a Polyline object based on the array of points
    # Append to the list of Polyline objects
    features.append(
        arcpy.Polyline(
            arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in feature])))

# Persist a copy of the Polyline objects using CopyFeatures
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features, "d:/scratch/polylines.shp")
```

I try to create 3D polyline and fail. Script creates polylineZ shapefile, but all features are flat with Z=0 at vertices. What is wrong here please?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've got working 3d polyline code (from text file) if you're interested. Perhaps it's in the CopyFeatures

Comment: yes please. It's bugging me badly. Could you also please test above code to see if result is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is complete working code (for what it's worth), one of the first arcpy tools I translated from 9.3 so it's still a little clunky.:

```
import sys, os, string, arcpy

InFolder   = sys.argv[1]
OutCoSys   = sys.argv[2]
ShapeName  = sys.argv[3]

#ShapeName = "JustFlightLinesNew.shp"
ShapePath = InFolder
ShapeFile = "%s\\%s.shp" % (ShapePath,ShapeName)

if string.upper(OutCoSys) == "48":
    OutCoSys = "PROJCS['GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_48',GEOGCS['GCS_GDA_1994',DATUM['D_GDA_1994',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0],UNIT['Degree',0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000],PARAMETER['False_Northing',10000000],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',105],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0],UNIT['Meter',1]]"
elif string.upper(OutCoSys) == "49":
    OutCoSys = "PROJCS['GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_49',GEOGCS['GCS_GDA_1994',DATUM['D_GDA_1994',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0],UNIT['Degree',0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000],PARAMETER['False_Northing',10000000],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',111],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0],UNIT['Meter',1]]"
elif string.upper(OutCoSys) == "50":
    OutCoSys = "PROJCS['GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_50',GEOGCS['GCS_GDA_1994',DATUM['D_GDA_1994',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0],UNIT['Degree',0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000],PARAMETER['False_Northing',10000000],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',117],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0],UNIT['Meter',1]]"
elif string.upper(OutCoSys) == "51":
    OutCoSys = "PROJCS['GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_51',GEOGCS['GCS_GDA_1994',DATUM['D_GDA_1994',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0],UNIT['Degree',0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000],PARAMETER['False_Northing',10000000],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',123],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0],UNIT['Meter',1]]"
elif string.upper(OutCoSys) == "52":
    OutCoSys = "PROJCS['GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_52',GEOGCS['GCS_GDA_1994',DATUM['D_GDA_1994',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0],UNIT['Degree',0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000],PARAMETER['False_Northing',10000000],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',129],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0],UNIT['Meter',1]]"
elif string.upper(OutCoSys) == "53":
    OutCoSys = "PROJCS['GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_53',GEOGCS['GCS_GDA_1994',DATUM['D_GDA_1994',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0],UNIT['Degree',0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000],PARAMETER['False_Northing',10000000],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',135],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0],UNIT['Meter',1]]"
elif string.upper(OutCoSys) == "54":
    OutCoSys = "PROJCS['GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_54',GEOGCS['GCS_GDA_1994',DATUM['D_GDA_1994',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0],UNIT['Degree',0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000],PARAMETER['False_Northing',10000000],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',141],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0],UNIT['Meter',1]]"
elif string.upper(OutCoSys) == "55":
    OutCoSys = "PROJCS['GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_55',GEOGCS['GCS_GDA_1994',DATUM['D_GDA_1994',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0],UNIT['Degree',0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000],PARAMETER['False_Northing',10000000],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',147],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0],UNIT['Meter',1]]"
elif string.upper(OutCoSys) == "56":
    OutCoSys = "PROJCS['GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_56',GEOGCS['GCS_GDA_1994',DATUM['D_GDA_1994',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0],UNIT['Degree',0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000],PARAMETER['False_Northing',10000000],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',153],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0],UNIT['Meter',1]]"
else:
    print "Unknown coordinate system"
    OutCoSys = ""

if not os.path.exists(ShapeFile):
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(ShapePath,ShapeName,"POLYLINE","","DISABLED","ENABLED",OutCoSys)
    arcpy.AddField_management(ShapeFile,"oFile","TEXT")
    arcpy.AddField_management(ShapeFile,"FileName","TEXT")
    arcpy.AddField_management(ShapeFile,"RefStat","TEXT")

LCur = arcpy.InsertCursor(ShapeFile,OutCoSys)

for DPath, DName, FNames in os.walk(InFolder):
    print DPath
    for ThisFile in FNames:
        FName, FExt = os.path.splitext(ThisFile)
        if (FExt.lower() == '.coo'):
            LArray = arcpy.Array()
            NewLine = LCur.newRow()
            FirstPoint = 1
            with open(DPath + "\\" + ThisFile) as InFile:                        
                for TextIn in InFile:
                    Stext = TextIn.split(" ")
                    if len(Stext) == 4:                                
                        pX = float(Stext[0])
                        pY = float(Stext[1])
                        pZ = float(Stext[2])
                        ThisPoint = arcpy.Point(pX,pY,pZ)
                        LArray.add(ThisPoint)
                print "Points done"
                PolyLine = arcpy.Polyline(LArray,OutCoSys,True)
                print ("oFile : " + FName[0:len(FName)-3])
                NewLine.setValue("oFile",FName[0:len(FName)-3])
                NewLine.setValue("FileName",ThisFile)
                NewLine.shape = PolyLine
                LCur.insertRow(NewLine)
                del NewLine
del LCur
```

It uses an insert cursor on a feature class to write lines directly...

Comment: Got it. The key is True parameter in PolyLine = arcpy.Polyline(LArray,OutCoSys,True)

Comment: Spot on! According to the docs http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000008000000 when creating your polyline the third parameter (has_z) needs to be set to true or it will ignore the embedded Z values.