# Update from/to Z from attributes using arcpy Update Cursor

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, cursor, elevation

Trying to update Z values onto some point and line features from the level attributes on each feature.  My script works fine on points - the previous Z values of `0` now have the same values as the level field.  It doesn't work on my line features though.

I guess I can't write to the `firstPoint.Z` and `lastPoint.Z` on each line, however it is giving no errors at all (the script exits successfully).

```
pointFields = ['SHAPE@Z', 'Level']
lineFields = ['SHAPE@', 'FromLevel', 'ToLevel']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(pointFC, pointFields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = row[1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lineFC, lineFields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0].firstPoint.Z = row[1]
        row[0].lastPoint.Z = row[2]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Not all of my lines are 2-point lines, but I only want to update the first and last vertex of each line with the `FromLevel` and `ToLevel` values from the attribute table.  I'm trying to modify the code from [How to update the Z value using an UpdateCursor?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135916/how-to-update-the-z-value-using-an-updatecursor) however I am trying to figure out how to update only the first and last points of my line.

Here is what I've attempted based on one of the answers from the other Q&A

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lineFC, lineFields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        newGeom = arcpy.Array()
        for part in row[0].getPart():
            newPart = arcpy.Array()
            for pnt in part:
                if pnt != None:
                    if pnt == row[0].firstPoint:
                        newPnt = arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y, row[1])
                    elif pnt == row[0].lastPoint:
                        newPnt = arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y, row[2])
                    else:
                        newPnt = arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y, 0)
                    newPart.add(newPnt)
            newGeom.add(newPart)
        newShape = arcpy.Polyline(newGeom)
        row[0] = newShape
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

But still it completes without error yet no `Z` values are present.

How can I update only the first and last vertices of my line with the Z values from attributes?

---

It does appear that `if pnt == row[0].firstPoint:` isn't working.  I did a `print row[0].firstPoint` and a `print pnt` and they return exactly the same values, yet it's not going into that `if`

```
print "First Point = {}".format(row[0].firstPoint)
print "Pnt = {}".format(pnt)
```

returns

```
First Point = 1875883.117 5826666.937 0 NaN
Pnt = 1875883.117 5826666.937 0 NaN
```

Yet it still hits the `else`.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147184/creating-polylinez-in-arcpy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to fix your new shape line to contain z values.

```
newShape = arcpy.Polyline(newGeom, None,  True, False)
```

The default is false

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/polyline.htm

I also had this as my if statement for the first point

```
if (row[0].firstPoint.X, row[0].firstPoint.Y) == (pnt.X, pnt.Y):
```

and last point

```
if (row[0].lastPoint.X, row[0].lastPoint.Y) == (pnt.X, pnt.Y):
```

Comment: Thanks JamesLeversha, forcing the Z Values into my new shape has done the trick